# CSS text-align:center is incompatible with position

Tags: css, css-position

i'm trying to fix the position of a div while this div's alignment is centered, but when i enter position (whether fixed or absolute) alignment to center is disturbed. what's the cause?

```
#stage {text-align: center; position:fixed;}
```

Comment: You should post the entire part that is **ocurring the problem**, not just the CSS.

Comment: It's not affected. The *text* is still aligned to the center *of the `#stage` element*. If it's not aligned to the center of the viewport or some container in between, that's because the `#stage` element is no longer in the same position.

Comment: how can i fix it then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to define a width for the fixed-position element. By default it is only as wide as its contents and aligned to the left top.

The way you describe it, probably `width: 100%` would be the adequate value, which stretches the element across the whole width, in which case the text-centering you applied will be effective.